# What part of speech is 'to marry' in 'I want to marry him'

Tags: grammar, infinitives, parts-of-speech

The first sentence can be paraphrased 'She wants something' which tells me that the infinitive **acts** as a noun.
Can someone explain in detail how to categorise 'to marry' in the second sentence. Does it still **act** as a noun and if so, why?

> She wants **to marry**.
>
> She wants **to marry** him.

Comment: It's a verb in both sentences. You can want _to do_ something as well as wanting a thing.

Comment: @KateBunting Is it not an infinitive acting as a noun?

Comment: 'to marry', seen on its own, is a verb, I agree with you, but it doesn't function as one in the example sentences. I'd argue that 'want' is the only verb.

Comment: I want to run, I need to sleep, I hope to win. What are run, sleep, and hope if not verbs here?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey But when I read this article, https://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/infinitive.html, it has several examples of infinitives. I am totally confused.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, I agree with DhanishthaGosh, they are certainly not verbs with the exception of 'hope'.  The verbs are 'want' and 'need'.

Comment: "We always follow want with a complement of some kind. The complement completes the meaning of the clause. The complement can be a noun or pronoun as an object, **or a verb in the to-infinitive form**, or an object plus a verb in the to-infinitive form:"  [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/want)

Comment: Some grammars refer to certain infinitives as noun phrases, as in "To err is human".  I think this is a confusing way of looking at things and that these 'to'-clauses or infinitival clauses should not be considered nouns.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh  [*I am totally confused.*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/261022/what-part-of-speech-is-to-marry-in-i-want-to-marry-him#comment489315_261022) Well parts of that explanation is indeed confusing. Never have I heard "to call" in "The person to call is Kim" described as a verb that acts like an adjective. I'd say that example is a reduced relative clause (the person [that you need] to call is Kim)

Answer (score -2):

Both examples use the phrase **"to marry"** as a verb, since one must perform an action to become married (a state of being).

However, the second sentience adds an identifier, allowing the reader to understand that the subject wants to marry someone in particular. The first phrase could have the context that she likes the idea of marriage and would like to be married.